# How to remove border of select option in ie browser

Tags: internet-explorer, border

Could someone tell me  **"How to remove border of select option in ie browser"**

Here is the link below of my problem

http://postimg.org/image/6cz4vmjen/

Comment: [`-ms-expand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pseudo-element might be useful.

Comment: Could you please elaborate some more about this?